# How to create 3D printing file (e.g. STL, OBJ and IGES etc.) from DEM?

Tags: software

I have DEM with 1 m resolution, how can I create 3D printing file (e.g. STL, OBJ and IGES etc.) from DEM?

Comment: Welcome to the stack. I suggest you take the [tour]: "What is best" questions are not allowed on the stack usually, as recommendations don't work in the Q&A style it tries to serve. If you would reword to "How to" that IS an answerable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered on a sister site, GIS Stack Exchange. It's a rather comprehensive answer posted, which means it's impractical to summarize here.

[GIS answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228827/generating-stl-3d-file-from-raster-aster-gdem-data)

The answer does indicate that a plug-in for QGIS software is needed in order to accomplish this objective. If you do not use/have the QGIS software, my answer is invalid.  All three answers to the question linked above appear to point to the same program/plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was tried that QGIS plugin before when input DEM is  5MB the output is around 700MB. When I try bigger size DEM the plugin stop working. So if I want to deal with big DEM is there any better solution?